# i have a problem with firebase auth in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i have this error when i run my app on debug mode
i want to print auth token but when i reload the app i received this message
D

```
> /ViewRootImpl@22a08dc\[MainActivity\]( 6846): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,720,1480) new=(0,0,720,1480) req=(720,1480)0 dur=14 res=0x3 s={true 4058093568} ch=false
> E/flutter ( 6846): \[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)\] Unhandled Exception: \[firebase_messaging/unknown\] java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
> E/flutter ( 6846): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
> package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:653
> E/flutter ( 6846): #1      MethodChannel.\_invokeMethod
> package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:296
> E/flutter ( 6846): \<asynchronous suspension\>
> E/flutter ( 6846): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod
> package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:499
> E/flutter ( 6846): \<asynchronous suspension\>
> E/flutter ( 6846): #3      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.getToken
> package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:224
> E/flutter ( 6846): \<asynchronous suspension\>
> E/flutter ( 6846):
```

i tried to delete build folder and rebuild it and it's not works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: tried to check your firebase authentication, and check inside of sign-in method. is your chosen auth already enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the latest firebase_auth and firebase_core packages. If the issue still persists, check whether you have integrated firebase properly. Delete the firebase_options.dart file (android) and try to integrate your firebase project with your flutter application again